# Backup/mirroring software with file name obfuscation

Tags: windows, backup, mirroring, obfuscate

I'm looking for a mirroring/backup program that will obfuscate the file name of the files being mirrored.  For example, say I have a file with something incriminating in the file name.  I'd like the file name to be encrypted/obfuscated when I store the mirror of my data on another computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't have the incriminating file in the first place - have you ever thought about that?  ...  The thought police are approaching your door...

Answer (score 3):

Just use Truecrypt on a USB thumbdrive. http://www.truecrypt.org/ Having an encrypted filesystem is better than obfuscating filenames.

Comment: ...especially when using TrueCrypt, which is an excellent recommendation.  Obfuscation of filenames doesn't really stop people from searching files anyway since it's a trivial matter for most file searching tools to search file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use BoxCryptor. BoxCryptor is a Windows implementation of 'encfs' for Unix systems. It is an encrypted filesystem that overlays any arbitrary filesystem you're already using. When you read and write files, their contents and their filenames are encrypted and decrypted with a system that ties back to your passphrase you used to mount it.

Unlike truecrypt, the cryptography happens at the level of individual files. You don't have to allocate space ahead of time.